# After capistrano deploy, there is no git repo in current path

Tags: ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

I am deploying our rack app using capistrano 3. We can deploy branches as we expect. However after deployment, when I login to server in current folder with all the codes, I don't see .git. Even I git init, the next time I deploy, it will get lost again. Is there anyway I can keep .git and track which branch we are deploying? Thanks

Comment: [Possibly related](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/757) issue.

Comment: Are you trying to run a git command in the `current` directory to know the deployed branch?

Comment: Yes, it will say not a git repo. Sometimes we make changes directly in the server, it would be nice to see what has been changed.

Answer (score 2):

The `current` directory is not a git working copy. Capistrano purposely does not include the `.git` directory.

The actual git repository can be found in the `repo` directory that is alongside the `current` directory, but I don't think that is what you are asking for. It sounds like you want to be able to figure out what branch or SHA was used to deploy the contents of `current`.

Also alongside `current` should be a file named `revisions.log`. If you `tail` it you can see the most recent releases, including the branch, SHA, and user that performed the release:

```
$ tail -n 3 revisions.log 
Branch master (at 609bf349776b24f85f85b1950b92314b2d8f3bdc) deployed as release 20170927161115 by mbrictson
Branch master (at 6a77bde58a2de42428b44da669c8f01475d6cd46) deployed as release 20171107004019 by mbrictson
Branch master (at 6d0395ca4067180e0d76735c36b6852691b360ea) deployed as release 20171107011743 by mbrictson
```

Alternatively, you could write a custom Capistrano task to write the branch to a special file. For example:

```
desc "Write the branch to a .branch file in the release that was deployed"
task :write_branch do
  on release_roles(:all) do
    within release_path do
      execute :echo, "#{fetch(:branch)} > .branch"
    end
  end
end

after "deploy:updating", "write_branch"
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. We actually want to make the current directory a `.git` directory. It looks like it's not possible.

Comment: @diwu86 It's possible if you are willing to write some code. You could redefine the `git:create_release` task to execute a `cp -r` instead of `git archive`. I can provide an answer along those lines if that's what you're looking for.